# Stuck in a quadratic reciprocity problem

Tags: elementary-number-theory, quadratic-residues, quadratic-reciprocity

I've recently started studying elementary number theory. Now I'm going through the topic of quadratic reciprocity. I'm having trouble trying to show that $n$ and $k$ are even numbers whenever $60k+7$ is a prime factor of $10^{2n} +8\cdot 10^{n} +1$. I don't really know how the quadratic reciprocity stuff comes into play here. Can anyone give me a hint on how to prove it?

Comment: $10^{2n}+8\cdot 10^n+1=(10^n+4)^2-15$. So, if $p$ prime divides that thing, then $-15$ is a quadratic residue mod $p$. So, $1=\binom{-15}{p}=\binom{-1}{p}\binom{3}{p}\binom{5}{p}$. Enjoy reversing those Jacobi symbols using QR.

Comment: FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%2410%5E%7B2n%7D%2B8%5Ccdot%2010%5E%7Bn%7D%2B1%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%2460k%2B7%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Aprime%2C%20OR%20content%3Aeven&p=1), there's the AoPS threads [Prime factors and powers of 10](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1569069p9623625) and [10^2n +8.(10^n) +1 prime factors](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2501328p21113755).

Comment: @NDB Thanks! I didn't even think about completing the square; thought it was way more complicated than this.

Comment: Well, it is only completing squares to make squares appear. I don't know if this one leads to the solution or part of it. I haven't checked. See how in the link above they complete other squares.

Comment: given a quadratic form  $f(x,y) = A x^2 + B xy + C y^2 $   with  $\gcd(A,B,C) = 1$   and $ \Delta = B^2 - 4AC $  nonzero and not a square:  if $A x^2 + B xy + C y^2  \equiv 0 \pmod p$   and $ (\Delta | p) = -1, $ then both $p|x$ and $p|y$   so that $A x^2 + B xy + C y^2  \equiv 0 \pmod {p^2}$  For you, $(A,B,C) = (1,8,1)$  and then $x = 10^n, \; \; y=1 . \; \; $